# Boots into blank screen

Tags: release-freya

I had Freya 0.3.2 working perfectly recently until I decided to install an AMD driver. After the installation I restarted my computer and all it boots to is a black screen. It goes past the Enter BIOS prompt then shows the Elementary OS logo but after the logo it just goes to a black screen and does nothing.

I can get into grub cmd line and the grub menu but when I choose elementary OS the same thing happens, if I go to recovery mode it goes to a BlackBox etc command line and no cmd works.

Edit: This is probably irrelevant but I have a Raspberry Pi 2 lol, in case I can use it to help me out

Comment: When the black screen appears, do you have access to terminal by typing CTRL+ALT+F1?